# When is the submonoid preserving a subspace finitely generated?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, geometric-group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $T$ be a topological space with at least one open set whose closure is not open.

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group acting by homeomorphisms on $T$. Let $S\subset T$ be a subspace.

Under what conditions is the monoid of elements of $G$ mapping $S$ to $S$ finitely generated?

Comment: This seems too general to have any reasonable answer. Indeed just choose $T=G$ with discrete topology, then the "semi-stabilizer" (in this sense) of any submonoid $M$ of $G$ equals $M$.

Comment: @YCor: it’s reasonable to ask for sufficient conditions (along the lines of the Schwarz—Milnor Lemma for groups).

Comment: @HJRW To add a bit in this direction, Gray & Kambites have proved that a monoid acting with certain properties $xyz$ on a geodesic semimetric space is finitely generated (so essentially Schwarz-Milnor for monoids). The situation in the question is particularly nice, as all monoids arising this way are of course cancellative, in which case one can say a bit more.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda: that sounds like a potential answer!

Comment: @Nassim: would you be willing to assume that $T$ is path-connected?

Comment: If you take a finitely generated infinite residually finite group G like a free group then you always have open sets in the profinite toplogy whose closure is not open.  So then as @YCor says you are basically classifying finitely generated submonoids.  So you need serious constraints.